# Using arrays to populate adjacent cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with every other column populated with numbers 1-9, starting in different rows.  I wrote the following sub to populate "Test [number]" in the cell to the right of the populated cell in each column.

I am running into two different issues that I just can't figure out.  See screenshots below for before and after examples.

**1. Column H's values start in row 1, but the code starts the population in row 2**

**2. None of the resulting "Test [number]" cells go past row 9**

Code:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim crng As Range
Dim carr() As Variant
Dim rarr() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
c = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
For j = 1 To c
If Not Columns(j).Find(what:="*", after:=Columns(j).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing And Columns(j).Find(what:="test", after:=Columns(j).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    r = Columns(j).Find(what:="*", after:=Columns(j).Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(r, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp))
    rarr = rng.Value
For i = r To UBound(rarr, 1)
    Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "test " & (i - r) + 1
Next i
End If
Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

I'm pretty new to using arrays in my code, so I wouldn't be surprised if my method is off.  That being said, I'm stumped that `UBound(rarr,1)` is not returning the last cell when `rng` = `.Range(.Cells(r, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp))`.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column H was starting in row 2 because you were asking the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) to start `after:=Columns(j).Cells(1, 1)`. I've changed that to start after the last cell in the column so that it loops back to the top.

`UBound(rarr,1)` is the upper boundary of the array. The [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions return the lower boundary and upper boundary or an array. It is the 'position within' `rng`, not the actual row on the worksheet.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim crng As Range
    Dim carr() As Variant
    Dim rarr() As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        lc = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        lr = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        For j = 2 To lc Step 2
            If CBool(Application.CountA(.Columns(j))) Then
                r = .Columns(j).Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(lr, j), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(r, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp))
                rarr = rng.Value
                For i = LBound(rarr, 1) To UBound(rarr, 1)
                    .Cells(i + (r - 1), j + 1).Value = "test " & i
                Next i
            End If
        Next j
    End With

End Sub
```

While you had implemented a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), it was not used throughout the code to denote the parent worksheet. Each of the [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx), [Range objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Range.Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837125.aspx) has to use the prefix `.` in order to inherit the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet  property.reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Being all those constants (numbers), I'd propose to have Excel work for us...

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        With ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(" & """" & "test" & """" & "&" & "COUNT(R1C[-1]:RC[-1]))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

    End Sub
```